# How are the values 515 and -515 (base 10) represented in 16 bit excess notation? How are they?

Tags: subscription

How are the values 515 <sub>10</sub> and -515<sub>10</sub> represented in 16 bit excess notation?

Answer (score 2):

From the details [here](http://www.pdcfaculty.org/rtureman/IntroCourses/CSC200/Projects/c200_ch01_excess_notation.htm):

Excess-N notation is simply a way of representing number where `N` is the zero point. You simply subtract the zero point from the encoded numbers to get the real numbers.

For a 16-bit excess representation, the zero point is 2<sup>15</sup> or 32768.

Therefore, `515` would be represented as `32768 + 515`, which is 33283<sub>10</sub>, 0x8203 or binary `1000 0010 0000 0011`.

Similarly, -515 would be represented as `32768 - 515`, which is 33253<sub>10</sub>, 0x7dfd or binary `0111 1101 1111 1101`.